# Second Metamathematics Book Suggestion

Tags: book-recommendation, meta-math

I worked through Kleene’s *Introduction to Metamathematics* and am interested where we stand in the field 70 years later.  What are some good text suggestions in modern metamathematics to follow this book?

Comment: Other publications are cool too, not just full textbooks.